# Download button automatically start downloading image

Tags: html, download

I am working on an website gallery and i would like the download button to automatically start the download of an image.

My code is below:

```
<form id='agreeform' method='post' action='images/gallery/cards/t_01.jpg'>

<p>Terms and conditions go here.</p>

<div id='remositorylicenseagree'>

<input name='agreecheck' type='checkbox' onclick='enabledl()' /><strong>I agree to the above terms.</strong>

<input class="button" id='remositorydlbutton' type="submit" value="Download" />

<input type="hidden" name="da" value="40a7068dfda9732133af1ec9254fc94e" />

</div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form method="get" action="image.jpg">
<button type="submit">Download</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, there is a new HTML5 download attribute that you could try:

```
<a download='image.jpg'>Download</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Carden, I used the html5 code and that worked. 
But is there a way to combine the <a download='image.jpg'>Download</a> code with the code that I had originally posted. 

Thanks

Comment: I think that you could just replace this code with the new line: `<input class="button" id='remositorydlbutton' type="submit" value="Download" />`

Comment: I have done that but the code download isn't activating. What am I doing wrong?

<div id='remository'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function enabledl () {    document.forms['agreeform'].elements['remositorydlbutton'].disabled=false }
</script>

<form id='agreeform' method='get' action='01.jpg'>
<div id='remositorylicenseagree'>
<input name='agreecheck' type='checkbox' onclick='enabledl()' />I agree<br/>
<input class="download" id='remositorydlbutton' type="download" value="DOWNLOAD" download='01.jpg' /><br/>
<p><a href="../../../images/gallery/cards/01.jpg" 
<br/></div></form>